# How to convert JOIN SQL query to relational algebra?

Tags: mysql, relational-algebra

Hi I'm hoping to get help with a really annoying problem.
I've been round in circles with this question but I am really struggling to convert this SQL query into its relational algebra equivalent.

Query:

```
SELECT
staff.STF_FirstNames AS `Doctor First Name`,
staff.STF_LastName AS `Doctor Last Name`,

patient.PAT_FirstNames AS `Patient First Name`,
patient.PAT_LastName AS `Patient Last Name`,

patient_makes_appointment.APP_DateTime AS `Appointment Time`

FROM staff
JOIN doctor                     ON staff.STF_ID = doctor.STF_ID
JOIN patient                    ON doctor.DOC_ID = patient.DOC_ID
JOIN patient_makes_appointment  ON patient.PAT_ID = patient_makes_appointment.PAT_ID
```

I'm ok with the basics of relational algebra but I am struggling to see how I can represent multiple joins with conditions.

Any advice is really appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need some looks like:

```
SELECT
  staff.STF_FirstNames AS `Doctor First Name`,
  staff.STF_LastName AS `Doctor Last Name`,

  patient.PAT_FirstNames AS `Patient First Name`,
  patient.PAT_LastName AS `Patient Last Name`,

  patient_makes_appointment.APP_DateTime AS `Appointment Time`

FROM staff, doctor, patient, patient_makes_appointment
WHERE staff.STF_ID = doctor.STF_ID 
  AND doctor.DOC_ID = patient.DOC_ID
  AND patient.PAT_ID = patient_makes_appointment.PAT_ID
```

Comment: Ah, this seems a lot simpler! So when is it appropriate to use join over multiple selects?

Comment: I think join it's new notation. SQL specifies two different syntactical ways to express joins: "explicit join notation" and "implicit join notation". Although "implicit join notation" was deprecated in 1992, and its use is not considered a best practice, database systems still support it. [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))

Comment: I would downvote this so-called answer. It replaces one piece of SQL with a worse piece of SQL. I see no Relational Algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the Original Post, all of the join conditions are between attributes of the same name. For this use Natural Join in Relational Algebra. (Written as the bowtie symbol. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Natural_join_.28.E2.8B.88.29)  Natural Join is commutative, transitive, idempotent. So 'chains' of Joins can be written without needing parens. And chains of Joins are usually what you want if your schema design has been normalised sensibly. So Relational Algebra expressions are often cleaner than SQL FROM/WHERE clauses.

Ollie doesn't give the schema, so we don't know whether there are other attributes in the relations that are same-named. I'll assume not.

For SQL's AS, use Relational Algebra Rename (rho operator). Note that in Relational Algebra there's no need to prefix attribute names with their relation name. In fact that would be quite wrong, exactly because of the way that Natural Join matches by attribute name.

The solution goes:

```
rho <STF_FirstNames/`Doctor First Names`, STF_LastName/`Doctor Last Name`, ... >
(staff bowtie doctor bowtie patient bowtie patient_makes_appointment)
```